# How to remove words of a line upto specific character pattern...Regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want the words after "test" word from a line in a file. means in actuaaly, i dont want the words coming before "test" word.

thats the pattern...

e.g:

Input:

```
***This is a*** test page.

***My*** test work of test is complete.
```

Output:

```
test page.

work of test is complete.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's the pattern there. Could you clarify please?

Comment: pattern is: anything before "test" word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -n 's/^.*test/test/p' input
```

If you want to print non-matching lines, untouched:

```
sed 's/^.*test/test/' input
```

The one above will remove (greedily) all text until the last `test` on a line. If you want to delete up to the first test use potong's suggestion:

```
sed -n 's/test/&\n/;s/.*\n//p' input
```

Comment: thanks...it works!!! Actually my try is : sed 's/^.\+test\/test/g' .... but it doesnt work

Comment: can you please explain when to use '.*' and when to use '.\+' ? i am newbie in regex... thanks in advance. I appreciat if you give me actually useful links for regex tutorail...

Comment: with sed, it is best to avoid `+` altogether. But if you must, use it if you really need something preceding `test`. With `^.\+test`, you can't match 'test is over' because the dot has to match at least one character with the `+`.

Comment: for a reference, this book is a must: http://regex.info/book.html, but I really don't know any online reference :(

Comment: @perreal `.*test` is greedy and will find the longest match not necessarily the first one. To guarantee first match always `s/test/&\n/;s/.*\n//` should be used. N.B. I've used `\n` as a unique character with which to set a marker, however a unique phrase would do just as well.

Comment: I don't have `input` and how do I pass the output of sed to variable. I want to use this in bash script, How do I do this, explain in detail.

Comment: input is a filename, to get the result in a variable do `var=$(sed -n 's/test/&\n/;s/.*\n//p' input)`. understand.

Answer (score 5):

A pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) one-liner:

```
while read x; do [[ $x =~ test.* ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}; done <infile
```

Input: infile

```
This is a test page.
My test work of test is complete.
```

Output:

```
test page.
test work of test is complete.
```

It reads all lines from file `infile`, checks if the line contains the string `test` and then prints the rest of the line (including `test`).

The same in [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

<s>sed 's/.*(test.*)/\1/' infile</s> (Oops! This is wrong! `.*` is greedy, so it cuts too much from the 2nd example line). This works well:

```
sed -e 's/\(test.*\)/\x03&/' -e 's/.*\x03//' infile
```

I did some speed testing (for the original (wrong) [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) version). The result is that for small files the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution performs better. For larger files [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is better. I also tried this [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) version, which is even better for big files:

```
awk 'match($0,"test.*"){print substr($0,RSTART)}' infile
```

Similar in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -ne 's/(.*?)(test.*)/$2/ and print' infile
```

I used the two lines example input file and I duplicated it every time. Every version run 1000 times. The result is:

```
  Size |  bash  |  sed   |  awk   |  perl
   [B] |  [sec] |  [sec] |  [sec] |  [sec]
------------------------------------------
    55 |  0.420 | 10.510 | 10.900 | 17.911
   110 |  0.460 | 10.491 | 10.761 | 17.901
   220 |  0.800 | 10.451 | 10.730 | 17.901
   440 |  1.780 | 10.511 | 10.741 | 17.871
   880 |  4.030 | 10.671 | 10.771 | 17.951
  1760 |  8.600 | 10.901 | 10.840 | 18.011
  3520 | 17.691 | 11.460 | 10.991 | 18.181
  7040 | 36.042 | 12.401 | 11.300 | 18.491
 14080 | 72.355 | 14.461 | 11.861 | 19.161
 28160 |145.950 | 18.621 | 12.981 | 20.451
 56320 |        |        | 15.132 | 23.022
112640 |        |        | 19.763 | 28.402
225280 |        |        | 29.113 | 39.203
450560 |        |        | 47.634 | 60.652
901120 |        |        | 85.047 |103.997
```

Comment: @user1640065: One point not clear. What should be done if the line does not contain the word `test`. It is not printing anything right now.

Comment: in my case, every input line must contain "test". (Actuaaly i am parsing log file and do the work on specific pattern. In my case, "test" is actually "Exception" word.

Comment: @user1640065: I added the `sed` version, but I may recommend you to use the `bash` version, because it uses less resources as a `fork(2)` and `execve` system call is spared.

Comment: @Truey... but i got "sed: -e expression #1, char 18: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS" error when i have use "sed -e 's/.*\(test.*\)/\2/' infile"

Comment: @user1640065: And what is the difference between the pure `bash` and `sed` solution? I made a test running each 1000 times. `Bash`: 0.430s, `sed`: 10.361s! The `sed` version is 24 times slower!

Comment: @user1640065: I added some measurement to my answer. It can be seen that for larger files `sed` is better.

Comment: thanks for this kind of approach.... ya in my case i am parsing log files...which are of 2-3 Mbs... so i think sed is useful for me...  I appericiate your help.

Comment: @user1640065: I added an `awk` version. This is even faster for big files!